# WebGL texture on top of texture

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl

I'm working on a project where I incorporate a webcam stream onto a spherical geometry. As I'm new to shaders and want to learn how this works, I want to project the webcam into the sphere using a relatively normal size, on top of a static background image.

So the webcam video has to cover only a small portion of the sphere, but the background image has to cover the entire sphere.

Currently my webcam image looks like this:
[current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huvRX.png)

But I want it to look like this:
[desired situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G91w3.jpg)

I have the following vertex shader:

```
            uniform mat4 projectionMat;
        uniform mat4 modelViewMat;
        attribute vec3 position;
        attribute vec2 texCoord;
        attribute vec2 texVideoCoord;
        varying vec2 vTexCoord;
        varying vec2 vTexVideoCoord;

        void main() {
          vTexCoord = texCoord;
          vTexVideoCoord = texVideoCoord;
          gl_Position = projectionMat * modelViewMat * vec4( position, 1.0 );
        }
```

And the following fragment shader, which currently draws "video" which is the webcam stream.

```
        precision mediump float;

        // Textures
        uniform sampler2D u_background;
        uniform sampler2D u_video;

        varying vec2 vTexCoord;
        varying vec2 vTexVideoCoord;

        void main() {
          vec4 background = texture2D(u_background, vTexCoord);
          vec4 video = texture2D(u_video, vTexVideoCoord);
          gl_FragColor = video;
        }
```

And my render function is set up as followed:

```
    this.program.use();

    //setup attributes
    //setup uniforms
    context.gl.uniformMatrix4fv(this.program.uniform.projectionMat, false, projectionMat);
    context.gl.uniformMatrix4fv(this.program.uniform.modelViewMat, false, modelViewMat);

    context.gl.bindBuffer(context.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertBuffer);
    context.gl.bindBuffer(context.gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.indexBuffer);

    context.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.program.attrib.position);
    context.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.program.attrib.texCoord);
    context.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.program.attrib.texVideoCoord);

    context.gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.program.attrib.position, 3, context.gl.FLOAT, false, 20, 0);
    context.gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.program.attrib.texCoord, 2, context.gl.FLOAT, false, 20, 12);
    context.gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.program.attrib.texVideoCoord, 2, context.gl.FLOAT, false, 20, 12);

    var u_backgroundLocation = context.gl.getUniformLocation(this.program.program, "u_background");
    var u_videoLocation = context.gl.getUniformLocation(this.program.program, "u_video");
    context.gl.uniform1i(u_backgroundLocation, 0);
    context.gl.uniform1i(u_videoLocation, 1);

    //activetexture/bind
    context.gl.activeTexture(context.gl.TEXTURE0);
    context.gl.bindTexture(context.gl.TEXTURE_2D, self.textureBackground);
    context.gl.texImage2D(context.gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, context.gl.RGBA, context.gl.RGBA, context.gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, self.canvasElement);
    context.gl.activeTexture(context.gl.TEXTURE1);
    context.gl.bindTexture(context.gl.TEXTURE_2D, self.textureVideo);
    context.gl.texImage2D(context.gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, context.gl.RGBA, context.gl.RGBA, context.gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, self.videoElement);

    //drawarrays/drawelements
    context.gl.drawElements(context.gl.TRIANGLES, this.indexCount, context.gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

I have no clue as how to continue to make the webcam appear scaled and part of the sphere as opposed to stretched over it. The webcam is a 100 degree camera, and should be positioned as such inside the sphere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your UV across the sphere, you could use it whole for the background image sampling, and smaller part of it for sampling the video texture.

```
vec2 vid_uv_start = vec2(0.2, 0.3);
vec2 vid_uv_end = vec2(0.6, 0.7);

uniform sampler2D u_background;
uniform sampler2D u_video;

varying vec2 vTexCoord;

void main()
{
    vec4 col = texture(u_background, vTexCoord);
    if((vTexCoord.x>=vid_uv_start.x && vTexCoord.x<=vid_uv_end.x)
        && (vTexCoord.y>=vid_uv_start.y && vTexCoord.y<=vid_uv_end.y))
    {
        vec2 adjustedUV = (vTexCoord-vid_uv_start)/(vid_uv_end-vid_uv_start);
        col = texture(u_video, adjustedUV);
    }
    gl_FragColor = col;
}
```

EDIT:

Here's the working shadertoy: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MsdSWs

Comment: Great, works fine. Obviously texture( should become texture2D( but this works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it would be to set your video UV coordinates so the 0<->1 range represents the area you want to see the video

In other words the background's UVs go

```
0,0       0.3    0.7    1.0
    +------+------+------+
    |      |      |      |
    |      |      |      |
    |      |      |      |
0.3 +------+------+------+
    |      |      |      |
    |      |      |      |
    |      |      |      |
0.7 +------+------+------+
    |      |      |      |
    |      |      |      |
    |      |      |      |
1.0 +------+------+------+
```

but the video UVs go

```
-1,-1      0      1      2
    +------+------+------+
    |      |      |      |
    |      |      |      |
    |      |      |      |
  0 +------+------+------+
    |      |......|      |
    |      |......|      |
    |      |......|      |
  1 +------+------+------+
    |      |      |      |
    |      |      |      |
    |      |      |      |
  2 +------+------+------+
```

Which makes the `......` part the part between 0 and 1

Then you shader would be

```
   precision mediump float;

    // Textures
    uniform sampler2D u_background;
    uniform sampler2D u_video;

    varying vec2 vTexCoord;
    varying vec2 vTexVideoCoord;

    void main() {
      vec4 background = texture2D(u_background, vTexCoord);
      vec4 video = texture2D(u_video, vTexVideoCoord);
      vec2 m = step(vec2(0), vTexVideoCoord) * step(vTexVideoCoord, vec2(1));
      gl_FragColor = mix(background, video, m.x * m.y);
    }
```